# How can I make my box-shadow look correct?

Tags: css

I have different `<div>`s with `box-shadow`. In Chrome desktop, the shadows look fine. However, in mobile, things get strange. I've read different posts with this issue and it was recommended I added a `-webkit-appearance: none;` but it doesn't do anything. Here's my [codepen](https://codepen.io/paulamourad/pen/qBrzWeV).

This is what I get in desktop (correct)

[image]

And this is what it looks like in mobile Chrome in an iPhone:

[image]

Here's my code (I'm using Bootstrap 4):

```css
.white-card-bg {
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(12, 26, 75, 0.24), 0px 3px 8px -1px rgba(50, 50, 71, 0.05);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(12, 26, 75, 0.24), 0px 3px 8px -1px rgba(50, 50, 71, 0.05);
  -ms-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(12, 26, 75, 0.24), 0px 3px 8px -1px rgba(50, 50, 71, 0.05);
  -o-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(12, 26, 75, 0.24), 0px 3px 8px -1px rgba(50, 50, 71, 0.05);
  border-radius: 24px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(12, 26, 75, 0.24), 0px 3px 8px -1px rgba(50, 50, 71, 0.05);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-3 nl-servicio-destacado-card btn" type="button" role="button">
  <div class="card-body white-card-bg text-center"> Content here </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm checked you codepen from my phone and it's looking fine

Comment: Not in my phone. The shadow is all messed up. I'm testing on Chrome, iPhone XR.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was wrong. Turns out it had nothing to do with the `box-shadow`it was the `type="button"` in my html that was causing the iPhone to add that strange shadow to the div. By removing that I solved this issue.